# Servlet Program HTTP status 404 (The origin server did not find a current representation)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

My Servlet Program File:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hello World!</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>HelloWorld</display-name>
  <description> Welcome to Tomcat World </description>


 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

When i am running the above program through my tomcat server it is giving me following error:

[image]

I am not using any IDE.
I am accessing the page through the following URL in browser

```
http://localhost:8085/myApp/servlet/HelloWorld
```

where myApp is the web application folder in my web-apps directory structure.

The class file is already generated. I have not created the war file.

When i try to start my tomcat server the window appears does not show the message of server startup in ---ms.
[Tomcat Server Not starting up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmI0q.png)

Comment: that 404 error is for `PlainTextServlet`, Is your app deployed ?

Comment: Sorry i uploaded the another img. Pls chk now..

Comment: is your app deployed ? can you hit `/myApp` and get to the app

Comment: You must provide the full class name for `servlet-class`. Full class name is including your package name. Example: your class have `package com.vn.app;` then full class name will be: `com.vn.app.HelloWorld`

Comment: Thanks Tuyen...i have created my first simple web-app and for that i have not used package. So, i think servlet-class element is correctly specified

Comment: Thanks Jigar... When i am running the application /myApp running is set to false and thus it displays the above 404 error.